# Rasterize SpatialPolygons with holes in R

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp

I'm trying to rasterize a SpatialPolygons object in a way that I get the number of polygons that overlap with each cell of the raster. My polygons have holes. The issue I have is that if two holes overlap it includes this overlap in the count.

I've created a toy example:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
hole <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))
p1 <- list(p1, hole)
p2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0))
p3 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-130,55), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-180,-20))
p3 <- list(p3, hole)

pols <- spPolygons(p1, p2, p3)

pols@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[2]]@hole
pols@polygons[[3]]@Polygons[[2]]@hole


r1 <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=180)
r <- rasterize(pols, r1, fun="count")
plot(pols, col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5))
plot(r)
```

I think this might be what was causing the problem associated to question [use R to rasterize shapefile with holes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29956660/2870670) , but there is no final solutions. In question [rasterize ESRI shapefile with holes but FALSE hole slots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12250471/2870670) the problem is that the holes are not properly formated, but that's not my case. If you look at the holes, they are both TRUE, see:

```
pols@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[2]]@hole
pols@polygons[[3]]@Polygons[[2]]@hole
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using package `fasterize` to do the rasterization (besides being faster) seems to avoid the problem:

```r
library(fasterize)
library(sf)

r1 <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=180)
r <- fasterize::fasterize(sf::st_as_sf(pols),
                          r1, fun = "count")
plot(r, col = rainbow(3))
```

[image]

HTH!

Comment: Fantastic! But, for curiosity, why `fasterize::fasterize(sf::st_as_sf(pols), r1, fun = "count")` rather than just `fasterize(st_as_sf(pols), r1, fun="count")` ?

Comment: Just because I usually prepend calls to functions of packages with the package name. This to avoid function shadowing and have a reminder of which package each function belongs to. It does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround. Rasterize each polygon first and then sum them up. By doing this the hole would be zero.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

# Create a list of Spatial Polygons
pols_list <- lapply(list(p1, p2, p3), spPolygons)

# Create a blank raster
r1 <- raster(ncol = 180, nrow = 180)

# Rasterize each polygon
r_list <- lapply(pols_list, rasterize, y = r1, fun = "count")

# Create a raster stack
s <- stack(r_list)

# Calculate the sum
r2 <- sum(s, na.rm = TRUE)

# Plot r2
plot(r2)
```

[image]